# Тач событие по пункту меню

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, touch-event

Есть сайт на Wordpress. Стандартным способом создана меню. Каждый пункт меню - это страница. При наведении на пункт меню **мышкой** выпадает список дочерних страниц. Но, если открыть сайт на iPad(к примеру), то при клике по пункту меню, оно не развернется, а произойдет переход на эту страницу.

Вопрос: как на планшетах посредством **CSS**(желательно), при нажатии на ссылку страницы в меню срабатывал не переход по ней, а разворачивался список других страниц

Comment: нужно для мобилок добавить стрелочку, и тач событие на него такое как `mouseleave` в `pc`.

Comment: Скорее всего, там нет никакого mouseleave. Либо hover, либо click. В общем, без ссылки на конкретную страницу помочь нечем.

Comment: Или создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: http://applecenter.sc/ пункт меню Ремонт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставьте такой код в свой файл script.js:

```
jQuery('.menu-item-has-children>a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        jQuery(this).parent('li').find('>ul').css('left', '-9999px');
        jQuery(this).removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).addClass('clicked');
        console.log(jQuery(this).parent('li').find('>ul'));
        jQuery(this).parent('li').find('>ul').css('left', '');
    }
});
```

Код я проверил в консоли браузера, он работает как надо.

Файл script.js должен быть в папке дочерней темы (а я смотрю, она не создана) - у вас установлена стандартная Storefront. Скрипт надо подключить через wp_enqueue_script() в functions.php.

Если не знаете, как создать дочернюю тему, задайте новый вопрос, я отпишусь. Вопрос по дочерним темам часто возникает, ответ будет полезен многим, я думаю.

Comment: т.е. через псевдоклассы данную проблему решить нельзя? У меня на этой теме стоит плагин для дополнительных свойств css, js и php. Дочернюю тему обязательно придется создавать?

Comment: Не псевдоклассы, а стили css )) Не важно. Вижу theme customization master, да. В нем вставьте вот этот код из ответа в js.

Comment: И да, через css это решить нельзя

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Помогло. А можно дописать скрипт, чтобы при повторном нажатии он сворачивался обратно? Ну или по свободному месту на сайте

Comment: Дополнил ответ.